# Question about implementing static Arrays class in python

Tags: python, arrays

Recently I am studying [mit cs6.006](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/). In the [recitation 2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/c08a3b63dfe5f6f6b32257d35f86ae63_MIT6_006S20_r02.pdf), **sattic arrays** are implemented as following:

```
class Array_Seq: 
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.A=[]
        self.size=0

    def __len__(self):   # My question here
        return self.size
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.A
    def build(self,X):   # My question here
        self.A=[a for a in X]
        self.size=len(self.A)

    def get_at(self,i):
       return self.A[i]
    def set_at(self,i,x):
        self.A[i]=x
    def _copy_forward(self,i,n,A,j):
        for k in range(n):
            A[j+k]=self.A[i+k]

    def _copy_backward(self,i,n,A,j):
        for k in range(n-1,-1,-1):
            A[j+k]=self.A[i+k]

    def insert_at(self, i, x): # O(n)
        n = len(self)
        A = [None] * (n + 1)
        self._copy_forward(0, i, A, 0)
        A[i] = x
        self._copy_forward(i, n - i, A, i + 1)
        self.build(A)

    def delete_at(self, i): # O(n)
        n = len(self)
        A = [None] * (n - 1)
        self._copy_forward(0, i, A, 0)
        x = self.A[i]
        self._copy_forward(i + 1, n - i - 1, A, i)
        self.build(A)
        return x
    def insert_first(self, x): self.insert_at(0, x)
    def delete_first(self): return self.delete_at(0)
    def insert_last(self, x): self.insert_at(len(self), x)
    def delete_last(self): return self.delete_at(len(self) - 1)
```

**My question**

I don't know how the function `len()` and `build()` work for the size:

when I use `build()`, this function will let `self.size=len()`, however, in the definition of `len()`, it will return self.size. I don't understand how it works.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: it's calling `len()` function on `self.A`, not `self`, which will cause calling `self.__len__()`

Comment: And it's another matter if this design is good, or better make size read-only property that will return the size of self.A. Current design is prone to error if len of self.A and self.size differ

Comment: @buran Thank you! So this function Build() use the inner function of python rather than the function we defined right?

Comment: it is using built-in [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)  which in turn call `self.A.__len__()` (`A` being regular list), not `self.__len__()` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.